Vue draggable not working on b-table, why?
I am using Vue 2 with Bootstrap Vue.
I have a table for which I would like to be able to drag and drop these rows.
But the way I implemented it does not work, but I don't know why.
I am guessing the table structure messes things up, that's the only idea of mine.
Here is the code:
I am using Vue 2 with Bootstrap Vue.
I have a table for which I would like to be able to drag and drop these rows.
But the way I implemented it does not work, but I don't know why.
I am guessing the table structure messes things up, that's the only idea of mine.
Here is the code:
<b-overlay
            :show="loading"
            rounded="sm"
            spinner-variant="primary"
        >
            <draggable
                v-model="accounts"
                @end="onDragEnd"
                tag="tbody"
                :move="onMove"
                :handle=".handle"
            >
                <b-table 
                    :fields="fields" 
                    :items="accounts" 
                    responsive 
                    head-variant="light"
                    tbody-tr-class="item"
                >
                    <template #head(handle)="data">
                        {{ '' }}
                    </template>

                    <template #cell(handle)="data">
                        <div class="handle-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-lg handle"></i>
                        </div>
                    </template>

                    <template #cell(icon)="data">
                        <b-card
                            class="my-2"
                            :style="{ 'background-color': data.item.color }"
                        >
                            <b-card-sub-title>
                                <span v-html="getIcon(data.value)"></span>
                            </b-card-sub-title>
                        </b-card>
                    </template>

                    <template #cell(name)="data">
                        <b>{{ data.value }}</b>
                    </template>

                    <template #cell(balance)="data">
                        <span><i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i> {{ data.value.toFixed(2) }}</span>
                    </template>

                    <template #cell(actions)="data">
                        <span class="cursor-pointer" v-b-modal="`bank-account-${data.item.id}-edit-modal`">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                        </span>

                        <modal
                            :id="`bank-account-${data.item.id}-edit-modal`"
                            :title="$t('actions.edit-bank-account')"
                            :ok-disabled="!canSubmit"
                            @ok-pressed="$refs.form.submit()"
                        >
                            <add-bank-account-form 
                                ref="form"
                                :can-submit="canSubmit"
                                :id="data.item.id"
                                @form-updated="updateFormValidity"
                                @item-added="payload => itemUpdated(payload, data.item.id)"
                            />
                        </modal>

                        <span class="cursor-pointer trash-icon" @click="deleteItem(data.item.id)">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
                        </span>
                    </template>
                </b-table>
            </draggable>
        </b-overlay>

    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    import Request from '@/mixins/Request';
    import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

    export default {
        components: {
            draggable,
        },
        mixins: [
            Request,
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                loading: false,
                accounts: [],
                canSubmit: false,
                fields: [
                    { key: 'handle', label: this.$t('misc.handle') },
                    { key: 'icon', label: this.$t('misc.type') },
                    { key: 'name', label: this.$t('misc.name') },
                    { key: 'balance', label: this.$t('misc.balance') },
                    { key: 'lastUpdate', label: this.$t('misc.last-update') },
                    { key: 'actions', label: this.$t('misc.actions') },
                ],
            };
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                activeUser: 'getActiveUser'
            }),
        },
        watch: {
            activeUser(newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    this.getBankAccounts();
                }
            },
        },
        methods: {
            async getBankAccounts() {
                this.loading = true;

                const { response } = await this.request('GET', '/bank-accounts', { params: { userId: this.activeUser.id, page: 1, perPage: 999 } });
                
                this.loading = false;

                this.accounts = response.data.data.map(account => ({
                    id: account.id,
                    handle: '',
                    icon: account.accountType.icon,
                    name: account.name,
                    balance: account.amount,
                    lastUpdate: account.updated_at ?? '-',
                    color: account.color,
                    actions: '',
                }));
            },
            getIcon(icon) {
                return `<i class="${icon} text-white fa-3x"></i>`;
            },
            updateFormValidity() {
                if (this.$refs.form) {
                    this.canSubmit = Object.values(this.$refs.form.item).every((value) => value);
                } else {
                    this.canSubmit = false;
                }
            },
            itemUpdated(data, bankAccountId) {
                this.$bvModal.hide(`bank-account-${bankAccountId}-edit-modal`);

                this.$toast.success(this.$t('messages.bank-account-updated'));

                this.getBankAccounts();
            },
            async deleteItem(id) {
                await this.request('DELETE', `/bank-accounts/${id}`);

                this.$toast.success(this.$t('messages.bank-account-deleted'));

                this.getBankAccounts();
            },
            onDragEnd() {
                // Handle the drag end event if you want to perform any actions
                // after the dragging is complete, such as saving the new order.
                console.log('Drag ended:', this.accounts);
                // Optionally, save the new order to the backend here.
                this.saveNewOrder();
            },
            onMove(evt, originalEvent) {
                // Additional logic to determine if a move is allowed
                // return true if allowed, false otherwise.
                return evt.from === evt.to; // Allow only within the same table
            },
            saveNewOrder() {
                // Here you would implement the logic to save the new order to the server
                console.log('New order saved:', this.accounts);
                // For example, you might make an API call to update the order
                this.request('PUT', '/bank-accounts/order', { data: this.accounts });
            },
        },
    };


does not work - What's actually happened?

The rows are not draggable.

you can try this package for drag & drop which name is vuedraggable. you just need to pass a array in the vuedraggable and all of functionality will be handle he. you can follow this stacture:
<draggable :list="data" item-key="dp-social">
</draggable>

this is simple use case of the vuedraggable. inside the vuedraggable you write your component code or logic.
